# Why does C# DirectoryServices not work with my LDAP server?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, openldap, directoryservices

I have a AD/LDAP server running in production that is working fine. I need to test things, so I created my own locally using phpldapadmin.

When I attempt to do a wildcard search on `objectClass`, my code throws. This only happens on my local server.

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: 'An invalid dn syntax has been specified.

I've tried multiple username syntaxes that `DirectoryServices` supports: they all work on the production server and fail on my local server. I can successfully get inside and navigate my local server using JXplorer.

```
class Program
{
    static void Run(string ip, string username, string password)
    {
        var authType = System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.None;
        var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ip, username, password, authType);
        var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry, "(objectClass=*)");
        directorySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;

        // throws here
        var searchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne();

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run("LDAP://validlocalip", "admin@test", "test");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like what you've passed as the `path` parameter to the `DirectoryEntry` constructor:

```
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ip, username, password, authType);
```

That parameter is an LDAP path, not just an IP. If all you have is an IP, then you can try "LDAP://ip" but usually you'd use your domain name: "LDAP://domain.com"

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.path

Comment: Hey, I'm passing in LDAP://ip which works for the production server ip, but not mine.